# Getting Error using Jersey client

Tags: java, json, service, jersey-client

I am using a jersey client to push data to the localhost. Here is my code -

```
public CloudConnection(JSONObject jsonPush) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/visual/savedata.php").build());
    ClientResponse response = webResource.path("restPath").path("resourcePath").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, jsonPush);
}
```

When i execute this in Eclipse it works fine and the db on my localhost is inserted with a recoord using savedata.php. But as soon i make a runnable jar of my project and run the jar it throws error -

```
 a message body writer for java type, class org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type, application/json was not found
```

How can i make this work normally when executing from the runnable jar?

Comment: show your complete command line on how you are starting the application from you executable .jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the Jersey client .jar on the `classpath` of the exectuable .jar as well as the Jersey .jar.

*If you are using Maven and you should be using Maven to build your artifacts, you can use the `shade` plugin and it will create an `Uberjar` of your code, and all the dependencies of your code in a single executable .jar file. Then you won't need to worry about specifying all the dependences and their transitive dependencies on the command line.*